# How to get QDockArea size?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt3

I want to get the `QDockArea` size when the user changes its size by dragging the Splitter. Is there any `signal` that emits when `QDockArea` size changes ? I'm using Qt 3.3.6 (please don't suggest to change the Qt version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could:**

Create a subclass of `QDockArea` and reimplement the [`resizeEvent`](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) function to emit a signal or directly call into some sort of manager object.

**Alternatively:**

How about using the manager object [as an `eventFilter`](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qobject.html#installEventFilter) on your `QDockArea`s and checking for [`QEvent::Resize`](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qevent.html#type-enum)?

Comment: Doc says that 
**"QMainWindow contains four QDockAreas which you can use for your QToolBars and QDockWindows, so in most situations you do not need to use the QDockArea class directly. Although QMainWindow contains support for its own dock areas it isn't convenient for adding new QDockAreas. If you need to create your own dock areas we suggest that you create a subclass of QWidget and add your QDockAreas to your subclass."**

But i don't understand what this mean exactly. Does this mean that i cannot add custom `QDockArea` class to `QMainWindow`?